# Usando Docker y Laravel tengo este error con MySQL: “SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory”

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

Tengo una app en laravel 5.2 que se conecta a mi base de datos mysql **local**, sin problemas. Pero, al colocar la app dentro de un contenedor docker, no logra conectarse a la base de datos y obtengo este error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Si cambio la constante DB_HOST en el archivo **.env** a 127.0.0.1 en vez de localhost, entonces obtengo este otro:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Lei que el problema podia deberse a no tener una ruta por defecto para el socket en el php.ini

```
$ ls -l /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
$ srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 nov 27 08:31 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Asi que lo agregue solo en el caso del pdo:

```
; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.default-socket
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Parte de mi archivo .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=developer
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

Mi database.php

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Utilice docker-compose para montar el contenedor, pues planeo crear otros microservicios mas adelante:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
   api_test:
      build: .
      ports:
         - "8181:8181"
      env_file:
         - ./.env
      environment:
         - PORT:8181
```

Mi Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1.5-apache

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mbstring
WORKDIR /api_test
COPY . /api_test
RUN composer install
RUN a2enmod rewrite
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

Uso:

- Debian 9.6, kernel 4.9.0-8-amd64
- Apache/2.4.25
- PHP 7.0.30-0+deb9u1
- MariaDB 10.1.37 database server

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: coloca la ip que te ha asigando tu router (si es DHCP) en lugar de localhost

Comment: Probe de esa manera, pero me aparece el mensaje de error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Comment: revisa en que puerto se ejecuta mysql `mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';`

Comment: Ya lo he hecho. Es el resultado que esperaba:  port  3306

Comment: ¿El servidor MySQL (o MariaDB en tu caso) se encuentra en el mismo contenedor docker o en otro diferente?

Comment: Viendo tu respuesta querría proponerte otra solución para aumentar el rendimiento si no piensas desplegar el servidor MySQL como servicio en docker. ¿Has pensado en [montar `/var/run/mysqld/` en tu contenedor como volumen](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)? De ese modo tendría acceso al socket UNIX a través de `localhost` (`/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`).

Comment: El servidor MySQL lo tengo en mi localhost. Pero seria interesante eso que propones. El respaldo sql es muy pesado y no quiero montarlo en otro contenedor. Pero como volumen tambien creo que mejoraria el rendimiento

Comment: @OscarGarcia estoy intentando hacer lo que sugieres, pero me encuentro con el mensaje [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.

Comment: ¿Qué te está dando ese error? ¿Qué has hecho para montar la ruta en el contenedor? Suena como que tu contenedor intentara arrancar o iniciar otra instancia de MySQL o algo así.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Lo declare en el docker compose de esta manera: volumes:
         - "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"
         - "dbdata:/var/lib/mysql"  y al final volumes:
   dbdata:

Comment: Para no abusar de los comentarios [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86569/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-pulidovpe). @PulidoVPE , no debes exponer los datos de MySQL al contenedor. En el chat te lo explico.

Answer (score 2):

Encontré la solución. 
O una solución que me sirve. 
Las encontré [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828599/how-to-configure-mysql-for-local-and-remote-access?rq=1) y [aquí](https://forums.docker.com/t/container-cannot-connect-to-the-hosts-mysql-database/3493/5)

El problema era el acceso remoto en mi base de datos mysql local. La red de mi contenedor era distinta a la de mi localhost. Y no tenia configurado mi mysql para recibir conexiones externas.

En el my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Y con los permisos

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'developer'@'%' identified by '123456';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

**EDITADO**

Olvidé agregar que cambiar mi DB_HOST por mi IP local (de la IP asignada por mi enrutador) a mi archivo .env también fue necesario.

Comment: Esto te ocurre por montar el servidor MySQL en el host, fuera del entorno docker. Si lo hubieras desplegado como servicio los contenedores tendrían acceso al servidor MySQL/MariaDB.

Comment: Ya antes habia configurado un docker compose con todo y base de datos funcionando. Lo tengo en mi github. Pero la base de datos de este es muuuy pesada y quise probar primero con mi localhost. Ademas, este no es para mi ;-)